# Will appending array's object in array will maintain object sort order every time?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm doing some operations like sorting, filter and grouped by some attributes of arrays object.

I'm adding objects of a filtered array in to another array like:

```
arrGroup.append(contentsOf: filteredArray)
```

My question is: will all of the objects maintain the same sorted order in the array every time, with 100% certainty?

Logically, will it add the object like

```
for object in filteredArray {
    arrGroup.append(object) 
}
```

**or**

```
for index in 0...filteredArray.count {
    let object = filteredArray[index]
    arrGroup.append(object)
}
```

For me, all are same, just difference in CPU cycle at run time. But my friend says that I should go with last option. Technically I'm getting same result for all three every time I debug my code.

Your suggestion please.

Comment: As it is array, I believe arrGroup.append(contentsOf: filteredArray) is always append in the same order of filteredArray

Comment: This should ask in review code.

Comment: Well, the second code snippet would cause a crash by trying to access `filteredArray[filteredArray.count]`, so definitely don't listen to your friend.

Comment: @Alexander, then arrGroup.append (contentsOf: filteredArray) is the best way right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, when you add an Array to another Array it will maintain the order as it is.
But yes if you are using Set then you might not get same order as it is not ordered collection but Array is ordered collection which maintains it's ordering until you changes it manually.

here is the code example :

```
var arr1 = ["1", "2" , "3"]     // Print arr1 : ["1", "2", "3"]
let arr2 = ["4", "5" , "6"]     // Print arr2 : ["4", "5", "6"]

arr1.append(contentsOf: arr2)   // Print arr1 : ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array` preserves whatever ordering you give it.

`Array.append(contentsOf:)` appends all items of the second array to the end of the first array, in order. Here's roughly what that algorithm would look like:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func myAppend(contentsOf other: [Element]) {
        reserveCapacity(self.count + other.count)

        for element in other {
            self.append(element)
        }
    }
}
```

## Techniques for iterating an array

### If you only need the elements

#### The preferred method

The preferred way to iterate the items of a `Sequence` is to use a typical `for-in` loop:

```
for element in array { // most preferred!
    // use the element
}
```

#### The discouraged method

```
for i in 0 ..< array.count {
    let element = array[i] // Avoid this!
    // use the element
}
```

I highly advise against this technique. The reason is because it's very easy to fall victim to an off-by-one-error. In fact, your very own example has it!

```
for index in 0...filteredArray.count {
    let object = filteredArray[index] // when index is filteredArray.count ... 
    arrGroup.append(object)
}
```

**Don't use this!** Any array of `n` elements has indices `0 ..< n`, ***not*** `0 ... n`. Attempting to access `array[array.count]` will crash your program.

#### Another valid but discouraged method

```
for i in array.indices {
    let element = array[i] // Avoid this!
    // use the element
}
```

### If you only need the indices

```
for i in array.indices {
    // use the index i
}
```

### If you need both the indices *and* the elements

```
for (i, element) in array.enumerated() {
    // use the index i and the element.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 for loops you have above are doing the same thing in terms of they will iterate from object #0 to the last object.

The first one is called `fast enumeration` and hence faster and more effective than the second.

And to answer your question. Yes the order will remain the same.

Comment: There's nothing faster about the first code snippet than the other. They work identically, behind the scenes.

Comment: @Alexander No they are not identical. It is called fast enumeration for a reason. Please check out this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33256/2640210

Comment: That has no relevance to Swift.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I guess now #1 is the best way.